# Google App Engine and PHPStorm running on localhost

Tags: google-app-engine, phpstorm

i am trying to launch google App Engine on my localhost via phpstorm, and i followed:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_r_O-YjzKo#t=85
```

When i run it on port 8080, (Default), i get this:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py" --php_executable_path=C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe .
```

In the PHPStorm Terminal. When i visit localhost:8080, localhost, 127.0.0.1:8080 or 127.0.0.1 i get page not found.

But if i launch the app via Google App Engine Launcher, it works fine on port localhost:8080.

Cant figure out the issue here, its quite odd.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: I couldn't run App Engine from PHPStorm while it worked from the console. I guess the problem is that the server first asks if you want to check for updates and you can't answer it in PHPStorm.

Press Y or N in the console then if you try running App Engine again from PHPStorm, it should work! In order to launch App Engine from console, type: `{google_appengine folder}/dev_appserver.py {project folder}`